# Is there any way to call method recurrently in symbolic general way?

Tags: c#, function, recursion

Consider two recurrent methods, late hours, complex code. In short, those two functions look like this:

```
void foo(int x)
{
  ... foo(x);
}

void bar(int x)
{
  ... foo(x); // oops, I meant "bar"
}
```

There are many times I wished (and I still wish) to have some symbolic call like "self", so I could rewrite it like this:

```
void foo(int x)
{
  ... self(x);
}

void bar(int x)
{
  ... self(x); // great! this is what i meant --> bar
}
```

So far the only hack I can think of, would be to write general function "self" which would on call check stack, get the caller, and call it. However it would not be possible to use it with inheritance:

```
void inherited(int x)
{
   base.self(x);
}
```

Thank you very much for your comments/ideas/etc :-)

Answer (score 0):

Pay more attention when writing code? I don't quite understand why you want it but maybe I'm missing something.

In short, I don't think you can do it without reflection and at that point it would be overkill.

Comment: With recursive Lambda functions it would be very useful. As it's now, you have to declare the variable containing the lambda function BEFORE declaring the body of the lambda function.

Comment: Yeah, that's a valid use case.

Answer (score 0):

Use F# ;)

(which requires functions are marked as `rec` if they recurse within themselves, and you have to "`and`" mutually recursive functions together - making your mistakes a compiler error.)

Comment: Oh well, this part of F# I already love -- especially forcing programmer to mark recursive functions, but for "a while" I'll stick to C#, not all F# features are such great.